# R - Models in caret don't finish when using # of cores > 64 in foreach & doParallel

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, r-caret

2 questions regarding a parallel back-end in R:

1) `parallel::detectCores()` doesn't detect the correct number of cores on my machine:

[image]

```
    parallel::detectCores(logical = FALSE)
    [1] 24
    parallel::detectCores(logical = TRUE)
    [1] 48
```

2) When running caret models, whenever I choose more than 64 cores, the model does not finish, even though each process has finished successfully (as it appears in the log). This happens regardless of how many cores my machine actually has as I tried it on a 32 core machine, and when I run `makeCluster(64)` it works and `makeCluster(65)` hangs.

```
library(caret)
library(doParallel)
library(xgboost)

iris <- iris[1:100,]
iris$Species <- as.factor(as.character(iris$Species))

tc <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", 
                   classProb = TRUE, 
                   verboseIter = TRUE,
                   allowParallel = TRUE)

stopCluster(cl)
cl <- makeCluster(65, outfile="D:\\R_data\\Log\\test.txt")
registerDoParallel(cl)

system.time(
    train.rf <- train(Species ~ .,data=iris, method="xgbTree", trControl=tc, metric = "Accuracy", verbose = TRUE)
)
```

The above hangs for 20-30 min or longer, never finishes execution, whereas the below code finishes in 20 sec:

```
> cl <- makeCluster(64, outfile="D:\\R_data\\Log\\test2.txt")
> registerDoParallel(cl)
> system.time(
    +         train.rf <- train(Species ~ .,data=iris, method="xgbTree", trControl=tc, metric = "Accuracy", verbose = TRUE)
    +     )
Aggregating results
Selecting tuning parameters
Fitting nrounds = 50, max_depth = 1, eta = 0.3, gamma = 0, colsample_bytree = 0.6, min_child_weight = 1, subsample = 0.5 on full training set
user  system elapsed 
1.71    0.76   22.63
```

Session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server >= 2012 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
    [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
    [1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
    [1] doParallel_1.0.10 caret_6.0-78      ggplot2_2.2.1     lattice_0.20-34   doSNOW_1.0.14     snow_0.4-2        iterators_1.0.8   foreach_1.4.3    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    [1] tidyselect_0.1.1    purrr_0.2.4         reshape2_1.4.2      kernlab_0.9-25      splines_3.3.3       colorspace_1.3-2    stats4_3.3.3       
[8] yaml_2.1.14         survival_2.41-3     prodlim_1.6.1       rlang_0.1.4         e1071_1.6-8         ModelMetrics_1.1.0  foreign_0.8-67     
[15] glue_1.1.1          withr_2.1.0         xgboost_0.6-4       bindrcpp_0.2        bindr_0.1           plyr_1.8.4          dimRed_0.1.0       
[22] lava_1.5.1          robustbase_0.92-7   stringr_1.2.0       timeDate_3042.101   munsell_0.4.3       gtable_0.2.0        recipes_0.1.1      
[29] codetools_0.2-15    psych_1.7.5         class_7.3-14        DEoptimR_1.0-8      broom_0.4.2         Rcpp_0.12.13        scales_0.4.1       
[36] ipred_0.9-6         CVST_0.2-1          ranger_0.8.0        mnormt_1.5-5        stringi_1.1.5       dplyr_0.7.4         RcppRoll_0.2.2     
[43] ddalpha_1.3.1       grid_3.3.3          tools_3.3.3         magrittr_1.5        lazyeval_0.2.0      tibble_1.3.4        randomForest_4.6-12
[50] tidyr_0.7.2         DRR_0.0.2           pkgconfig_2.0.1     MASS_7.3-45         Matrix_1.2-8        data.table_1.10.4   lubridate_1.7.1    
[57] gower_0.1.2         assertthat_0.2.0    R6_2.2.2            rpart_4.1-10        compiler_3.3.3      sfsmisc_1.1-1       nnet_7.3-12        
[64] nlme_3.1-131       
> version
_                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          3.3                         
year           2017                        
month          03                          
day            06                          
svn rev        72310                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
nickname       Another Canoe
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Recommendation:

My recommendation (though counterintuitive) is to reduce the number of Cores you are allocating to your cluster. Why?

- You only have 48 actual physical cores, hyperthreading (see below for explanation) implies you have 96 but this does not necessarily imply a true benefit (Generally somewhere between 15 and 30% net benefit) as the increase in the number of cores creates more arbitration.

Essentially, there is a cost of communication and coordination implicit in any parallel execution solution. If you reduce the number of cores being allocated you will find a sweet spot exists between parallelism and performance.

### Sixty-five cores failure

Why do 65 instead of 64 cores trigger failure? My sense is that that you are are hitting the [128 thread limit of Windows](https://github.com/tobigithub/R-parallel/wiki/R-parallel-Errors#lib-is-not-writable). The solution is to Recompile R or PRO and/or ask for a fix. Per the URL:

- This is an R limitation for max 127 nodes (2015). This is not a Windows threading limitation, however, can be also invoked by a memory limitation, because each rscript.exe (+conhost.exe) require at least 44 MByte RAM each. For a local Windows snow cluster with 99 clients, 4 Gbyte RAM are required.

---

## Background

To explain this situation my sense is we have to step back and provide some context as to the relationship between:

1. OS Dependencies [Windows versus Unix]
2. R Package relationships in the context of the OS dependencies

   - doParallel -> Parallel -> SNOW
3. Oversubscription of resources

#### parallel::detectCores()

Ok, using this as a framework lets start with `parallel::detectCores()`. The problem here is that Windows and Unix report different results. Per the `parallel` manual:

- *On Windows, the default is to report the number of logical CPUs. On modern hardware (e.g.Intel Core i7 ) the latter may not be unreasonable as hyper-threading does give a significant extra throughput. What `detectCores(logical = FALSE)` reports is OS-version-dependent: on recent versions of Windows it reports the number of physical cores but on older versions, it might report the number of physical CPU packages.*

Thus your results imply:

```
parallel::detectCores(logical = FALSE)
[1] 24
parallel::detectCores(logical = TRUE)
[1] 48
```

that you have 24 physical cores, and 48 logical cores.

So let's check that, you are running an [Intel Xeon E5-4640 v4](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Xeon/Intel-Xeon%20E5-4640%20v4.html). Well, a single E5-4640 v4 has 12 CPU and 24 logical threads. This implies you are running a *four-socket machine* as you report back 12 * 4 = 48 CPU, 24 * 4 = 96 logical cores.

So your OS (Windows) reports 48 Physical cores, your R instance reports 48 cores... what is the difference between a physical core (48) and a logical core (96)?

Well, in logical cores in this context pose an interesting conundrum.

- [Hyperthreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) is an 'innovation' developed by Intel to create an extra execution 'thread' on a single core, and is reported as a logical core. It does not double the capabilities of the core because it is actually sharing a lot of individual components that can only perform one function at a time.  But, it can do things like instruction setup.  So while the core is executing an instruction that it has already set up, the Hyperthread can be setting up another instruction.  It is important to note that there is only a single place on the core that can execute the instruction, so it has to wait for the currently executing instruction to complete.

thus, the essential problem here is that you are oversubscribing your physical resources.

I hope the above helps point you in the right direction.

Futher reading:

- https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/parallel_comp/
- https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf
- https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/html/00Index.html

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond, I will look into it and follow up (also will mark as accepted at the conclusion).

Comment: @BigTimeStats No problem, happy to help. I've hit some of the issues you mention when running R on Windows on TidalScale. (8 Node system, 6Tb of RAM, and 128+ Cores).